# Bivariate transformation, but i don't understand how to determine the set T

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X1 and X2 have the joint pdf h($x_1$,$x_2$)=8$x_1x_2$, 0 <$x_1$ < $x_2$ < 1, zero elsewhere. Find the joint pdf of Y1 = X1/X2 and Y2 = X2. Hint: Use the inequalities 0 <$y_1 y_2$ < $y_2$ < 1 in considering the mapping from S onto T.

I don't understand how to determine the set T. I know I would eventually get $Y_1$ = $X_1/X_2$ and $Y_2$ = $X_2$, then I would plug in $x_1$ = 0, $x_1$ = 1, $x_2$ = 0, and $x_2$ = 1 to the equation $X_1$ and $X_2$, is it right? I just don't understand how to determine the set T, because eventually I would get T = {($y_1,y_2$) : 0 < $y_1$ < $\infty$ and 0 < $y_2$ < 1}, which I'm not sure whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: You should explicitly define S and T.

Comment: the S would be {(x1,x2) : 0 < x1 < x2 < 1}, but I don't know how to determine the T

Comment: So $S$ is your support of $(X_1, X_2)$ while $T$ is the support of $(Y_1, Y_2)$.
First, you should try to find the inverse transformation $x_1 = g(y_1, y_2)$ and $x_2 = h(y_1, y_2)$. Next, plug this into the inequality of $S$ which determine its boundary. Last, simplify the set of inequalities.

Comment: I don't understand how to determine the set T. I know I would eventually get X1 = Y1/Y2 and X2 = Y2, then I would plug in x1 = 0, x1 = 1, x2 = 0, and x2 = 1 to the equation X1 and X2, is it right? I just don't understand how to determine the set T, because eventually I would get T = {(y1,y2) : 0 < y1 < ∞ and 0 < y2 < 1}, which I'm not sure whether it is right or wrong. @BGM

Comment: Say you determined $x_1 = y_1/y_2$ and $x_2 = y_2$, then you plug in to get $0 < y_1/y_2 < y_2 < 1$. Next simplify it

Comment: So I would get 0 < $y_1$ < $y_2^{2}$ < $y_2$, then I would take 0 < $y_2^{2}$ < $y_2$, then 0 < $y_2$ < 1. Because of that, 0 < $y_1$ < $y_2$ <1. So is it T = {($y_1$,$y_2$): 0 < $y_1$ < $y_2$ and 0 < $y_2$ < 1} or T = {($y_1$,$y_2$): 0 < $y_1$ < 1 and 0 < $y_2$ < 1}?

Comment: sorry i think i made a mistake, it is supposed to be $Y_1$ = $X_1$/$X_2$ and $Y_2$ = $X_2$, so that would be  0 < $y_1$ $y_2$< $y_2$ < 1. But then I don't understand how to get the T

Comment: Could you please format your question properly using MathJax?

Comment: sorry i think i made a mistake, it is supposed to be Y1 = X1/X2 and Y2 = X2, so that would be 0 < y1 y2< y2 < 1. But then I don't understand how to get the T @BGM